# How can I find the maximum daily sales grouped by product_id, year, and month

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with all the sales data like this:

| id | product_id | orderdate | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p1 | 20 Oct 2021 12:13:03 -0700 | 10 |
| 2 | p1 | 21 Oct 2021 12:13:03 -0700 | 10 |
| 3 | p1 | 21 Oct 2021 12:13:03 -0700 | 60 |
| 4 | p2 | 20 Nov 2022 01:13:03 -0700 | 80 |
| 5 | p2 | 21 Oct 2022 12:13:03 -0700 | 10 |
| 6 | p2 | 21 Oct 2022 12:13:03 -0700 | 90 |

I want to write a query that returns the date with max of total sales for each (product_id, month, year) combination

I can find daily totals for each product for each date.

```
select product_id, date(orderdate) date, sum(amount)
from sales
group by 1, 2
```

But, I don't know how to find the max value for every (product_id, month, year)

For example, the output from the above example should be

| product_id | year | month | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 2021 | 10 | 70 |
| p2 | 2022 | 11 | 80 |
| p2 | 2022 | 10 | 100 |

Comment: Please include the output you want.  You seem to be asking for two different results here.

Comment: The DATE_PART function will help you derive the Month and Year values from your dates.  So you can select DATE_PART(month, orderdate) and DATE_PART(year, orderdate) to get separate columns containing the month and year (which can then be grouped by, just as your current query is grouping by orderdate.  Have a go and see where you get to, then come back for some additional assistance

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added a sample output from the sample table. I hope that clarifies things. Sorry, I am probably not able to frame the question properly.

Comment: Then my answer below, using `RANK()`, is one option for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your current is what you want, except you wish to aggregate by year and month, we can try:

```sql
WITH daily_totals AS (
    SELECT product_id, DATE(orderdate) date, SUM(amount) daily_total
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY 1, 2
),
cte AS (
    SELECT product_id, TO_VARCHAR(date, 'YYYY-MM') ym, daily_total,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id, TO_VARCHAR(date, 'YYYY-MM')) rnk
    FROM daily_totals
)
SELECT product_id, ym, daily_total
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY product_id, ym;
```

Comment: I am not sure if this would give me the max daily amount for each product for each month, right?

Comment: @Ankit You never responded to my earlier comment under your question, but now you sort of have.  Try the updated answer.

Comment: This exact query didn't work, but it gave me the path forward. I modified your query to `with daily_totals as (
  select product_id, date(orderdate) date, sum(amount) daily_total from sales group by 1, 2
),
 cte AS (
    SELECT product_id, TO_VARCHAR(date, 'YYYY-MM') ym, daily_total,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id, TO_VARCHAR(date, 'YYYY-MM')
                        ORDER BY daily_total DESC) rnk
    FROM daily_totals
)
SELECT product_id, ym, daily_total
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY product_id, ym;` I can add an answer or if you modify, I can accept yours

Comment: @Ankit I have updated my answer per your comment.  Note that the `ORDER BY` inside the second CTE was superfluous and won't do anything.